# Viewing and Updating Data throught Modal Box In Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, view, modal-dialog, edit

guys. I need some help in viewing my data throught a modal box and replace it using update function.

Here's my button to view the modal box

```html
{{ Form::open(array(
                                'route' => array('edit_spk', 'id'=> $spk_data->id),
                                'method' => 'put',
                                'style' => 'display:inline'
                                ))
                            }}
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-line btn-rect" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editSpk"><i class="icon-pencil icon-white"></i> Edit</button>
                            {{ Form::close() }}
```

Here's my view code for this modal box

```html
<div class="col-lg-12">
{{ Form::open(array('url'=>'edit_spk','class'=>'form-horizontal', 'id'=>'block-validate')) }}                               
<div class="modal fade" id="editSpk" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                <div class="modal-dialog">
                                    <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="H4"> Edit SPK</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Distribution Code</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-10">
                                                <div class="input-group">
                                                    <input class="form-control" id="distribution_code" name ="distribution_code" type="text" data-mask="M99/99/99/9999"/>
                                                    <span class="input-group-addon">M99/99/99/9999</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Destination</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2">HLR</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" id="hlr" name="hlr" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2">First ICCID</label>
                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" id="first_iccid" name="first_iccid" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Last ICCID</label>

                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" id="last_iccid" name="last_iccid" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label col-lg-2">Quantity</label>

                                            <div class="col-lg-9">
                                                <input type="text" id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" />
                                            </div>                                       
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-actions no-margin-bottom" style="text-align:center;">
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-line btn-rect" id="confirm">Update SKU</button>
  </div>                                </div>
                                {{Form::close()}}
                                         </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
<!--END OF MODAL EDIT SPK-->

<!-- Dialog show event handler -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#editSpk').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
      $message = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-message');
      $(this).find('.modal-body p').text($message);
      $title = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-title');
      $(this).find('.modal-title').text($title);


      var form = $(e.relatedTarget).closest('form');
      $(this).get('.modal-body #distribution_code').data('form', form);
      $(this).get('.modal-body #destination').data('form', form);
      $(this).get('.modal-body #hlr').data('form', form);
      $(this).get('.modal-body #first_iccid').data('form', form);
      $(this).get('.modal-body #last_iccid').data('form', form);
      $(this).get('.modal-body #quantity').data('form', form);
  });

  <!-- Form confirm (yes/ok) handler, submits form -->
  $('#editSpk').find('.modal-footer #confirm').on('click', function(){
      $(this).data('form').submit();
  });
</script>
```

Here's the route :

```html
Route::put('spk/edit/{id}', array('as'=>'edit_spk','uses'=>'SpkController@edit'));
```

And here's the controller

```html
public function edit($id)
 {
  $spk = Spk::find($id);
  $spk->title = Input::get('distribution_code');
  $spk->body = Input::get('destination');
  $spk->done = Input::get('hlr');
  $spk->done = Input::get('first_iccid');
  $spk->done = Input::get('last_iccid');
  $spk->done = Input::get('quantity');
  $spk->save();
  
  Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated SPK !');
        return Redirect::to('spk_view');
 }
```

Can someone help me to get the data and view it into the element in modal box and make it updated using laravel ? thanks for your kindness :)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, here is how i solved it.
My modal is on the index.blade page, as follows:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" role="button" href="{{ URL::to('user/'.$user->id.'/edit') }}" class="btn btn-default"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

Then the modal:

```
@if(!empty($user))
    <!-- Form modal -->
            <div id="edit_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="icon-paragraph-justify2"></i> Edit User</h4>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Form inside modal -->
                        {!! Form::model($user,array('route' => ['user.update', $user->id],'method'=>'PATCH')) !!}

                            <div class="modal-body with-padding">                               
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <label>First name</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Chinedu"
                                         name="name" value="{!! $user->name !!}">
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
@endif

@if(!empty($user))
<script>
$(function() {
    $('#edit_modal').modal('show');
});
</script>
@endif
```

My controller methods are:

```
public function index()
    {
        //View all users
        $users= User::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
        return view('user.index',compact('users'));
    }

public function edit($id)
    {
        //
        $users= User::orderBy('name', 'ASC')->paginate(10);
        $user= User::findOrFail($id);
        return view('user.index',compact('users','user'));
    }
```

Hope this helps